# Excerpt Not Starting Correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, tag-wiki

The excerpt for the [excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag is not showing all of it's information. This is how it should start:

> Microsoft Excel is a spreadsheet application.

but it starts with:

> a spreadsheet application.

This is clearly a bug:
[image]

Surprisingly, the [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) tag starts properly. Can it be that the excerpt text is too long?

**update 16-09-2013**
Changed the excerpt for the [excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag to the following text:

> The spreadsheet application from Microsoft.

Now it fits, see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of redundant phrases - including some containing the name of the tag itself - that are not displayed on tags list, to help ensure there's room for the non-redundant parts of the tag excerpt.

The google spreadsheets tag wiki doesn't match any of these, so it's displayed in full.

For details, see: [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts)

Comment: Would it make sense to limit the amount of characters to be entered into the excerpt area? An excerpt should be a one-liner, at most a two-liner.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design. The first part matches the tag itself  so is deemed to be redundant. I don't know why the google-spreadsheets one doesn't do this.